# How to give a slave/node as a dynamic parameter in hudson?

Tags: automation, hudson

I have a list of jobs(say 20) in hudson, which are run in sequence(Job1,2,3,....20) and which are parameterized(parameters given for job1 are passed to other jobs) . 
All the jobs run on a node, say 'A'.Now if i wan't to run the same 20 jobs next time on server 'B', I have to go to each job's configuration matrix and change the node from 'A' to 'B'. Since I have 20 jobs, I've to do this tedious job of changing the node 20 times. Is there a way to give the node as a parameter when starting job1, so that i don't have to do put in a lot of effort everytime?

Answer (score 1):

We have one plugin Link : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin which allow to use NODE as Parameter

And in First job you can use the option in post-build action "Trigger Parameterized build on other projects" and then try to pass the node parameter to next job.